# transform: translateY() works different each device

Tags: css, user-agent

I applied

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%);
-moz-transform: translateY(40%);
-ms-transform: translateY(40%);
-o-transform: translateY(40%);
transform: translateY(40%);

//translateY(10%) on mobile
```

this on element.

on other computer or mobile. It looks good.
Like this

[image]

But on my computer. 
It looks weird.. 
like this (mobile on developer mode)

Why this happened??

this is my user agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give top or bottom value to work it properly. Some browsers need first position to translate it to the new position.

edit: or you just can give top: 40%;?

Comment: Nope "top:40%" maybe 40% of document's height. But translate(40%)is 40% of it's element...

Comment: I see your point. Have you tried adding `top: 0;` or `translate(0, 40%);`?

Comment: yes, but it just moved documnet's top based 40% of translateY